# Cannot assign a string value to typescript enum (Initializer type string not assignable to variable type)

Tags: typescript, enums

It seems that from TypeScript 2.4 onwards [String Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html)  are a feature.

However the following does not work:

```
enum Foo {
    A = "A",
    B = "B"
}

var foo : Foo = "A";
```

> Initializer type string not assignable to variable type Foo

String literals work:

```
type Foo = "A" | "B";
```

But what if I **want** to use an `enum`? Is there a way around this?

Comment: it seems to me that no answer provides explanation to why this won't work. From a similar issue on github:
"The intent of string enums is that the values of the enum are opaque (i.e. they can be changed behind the scenes without breaking consumers). If you don't want that behavior, it's easy enough to use the pre-string-enum workarounds to create similar union types.

Numeric enums allow assignments from arbitrary numbers because we need to support bitflag enums and the | / & / etc operators return number. There's no corresponding behavior for string enums that needs to be supported."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use an index expression to get the value of the enum:

```
enum Foo {
    A = "A",
    B = "BB"
}

var foo : Foo = Foo["A"];
var fooB : Foo = Foo["B"];
```

Note that the key will be the name of the member not the value.

You could also use a type assertion, but you will not get errors if you assign a wrong value:

```
var foo : Foo = "A"  as Foo;
var foo : Foo = "D"  as Foo; // No error
```

Comment: Though you won't get compile errors on attempt to use a value that does not exist in this enum with such approach

Comment: This won't work if enum is private and never exposed. Need a better solution for tests.

Answer (score 17):

As `Foo` is the enum so you can use the `.` as well to accesss the value of `enum` like below

```
var foo : Foo = Foo.A;
```

Answer (score 8):

While not a direct answer to the question *per se* (as it doesn't assign to enum but a derivative type), I discovered this which does solve my problem of allowing me to assign a `string` and guarantees that it's a part of the enum, and even allows me to avoid the redundant `A = "A"` when all that really matters is `A`.

You can use `keyof` [[1]](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to enumerate the properties on the `typeof` the enum (`Foo`)

```
enum Foo {
    A,
    B
}

var foo : keyof typeof Foo = "A"; // OK
var foo : keyof typeof Foo = "C"; // ERROR
```

Or on objects:

```
interface Bar {
    type: keyof typeof Foo
}

let obj: Bar = {
    type: "A" // OK
}
```

<sup>[*] I'll mark one of the other answers as accepted and keep this here for reference</sup>

Answer (score 7):

As described into the typescript [enum documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

you can use it in different ways :

```
Enum.A // Good way

Enum["A"] // Bad way

Enum[variable] // Good way
```

---

In your case

```
enum Foo {
    A = "A",
    B = "B"
}

// Bad way
const example1 : Foo = Foo["A"];

// Good way
const example2 : Foo = Foo.A;

// Good way
const example3 : Foo = Foo[variable];
```

---

You should **AVOID** the use of `example1` and focus on `example2` and `example3`. In any case, there is no point to write `"A"`.

Always prefer `Enum.A` and if you want to cast a variable as an enum use `Enum[variable]`.