# How can I cast a string to an enum in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

Enum definition:

```
enum Colors {
  Red = "red",
  Blue = "blue"
}
```

How can I cast some arbitrary sting (e.g. a result from a GET request) to the enum?

```
const color: Colors = "blue"; // Gives an error
```

In addition, why do integer enums work but string enums fail to have the same behavior?

```
enum Colors {
  Red = 1,
  Blue
}

const color: Colors = 1; // Works
```

Comment: already answered, please check those answers: [Create an enum with string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490560/create-an-enum-with-string-values) [Cannot assign a string value to typescript enum (Initializer type string not assignable to variable type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464141/cannot-assign-a-string-value-to-typescript-enum-initializer-type-string-not-ass)

Comment: The accepted  answer on that post is contradictory. The first way tells you how to access the enum value with the key which is not what i asked. The second way seems to work though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are sure that the strings will always correspond to an item in the enum, it should be alright to cast it:

```js
enum Colors {
  Red = "red",
  Blue = "blue",
}

const color: Colors = <Colors> "blue";
```

It won't catch the cases where the string is not valid. You would have to do the check at runtime:

```js
let colorName: string = "blue"; // from somewhere else
let color: Colors;
if (Object.values(Colors).some((col: string) => col === colorName))
  color = <Colors> colorName;
else
  // throw Exception or set default...
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does integer enum work off the bat but string enum does not work unless you cast to the type?

Comment: I cannot test right now but I quiet sure the `in` operator will check for the keys of the enum, not the values. In the example, `"blue"` will throw but `"Blue"` will pass. Number-based enums generates a reverse mapping but string-based ones does not.

Comment: For some reason, with this type of casting I keep getting the error: "JSX element 'Colors' has no corresponding closing tag", so I had to do the casting in a different way to make it work: color = colorName as Colors

Comment: In above code, change `.some(...` to `.find(...` so that it stops iterating through enum values if it finds the correct one.