# Using enum for event.target.value in Typescript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have an enum defining categories that can be selected via a form radio inputs:

```js
enum Category {
  PRACTICAL = 'practical',
  POSITIONING = 'positioning',
}
```

How can I use this enum in my radio group onChange handler function? This is what I am currently doing:

```js
const [filter, setFilter] = useState<Category>(Category.POSITIONING);

const handleFilterClick = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  setFilter(value); // <== Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Category>'
};
```

`setFilter(value)` is not working because typeof value is `string` instead of `Category`.

How should I handle this situation?

Comment: You need to convert your string to an enum, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62821682/how-can-i-cast-a-string-to-an-enum-in-typescript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typescript has no way to determine that `event.target.value` will be a member of that enum. So you will need to use a type assertion to tell typescript that you know those are the only possible values:

```
setFilter(value as Category);
```

Be aware that type assertions mean you're telling typescript not to check your work. If the JSX you've written actually has a way to set a value outside the enum, typescript will not be able to tell you about this.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Is the best practice in my case to just use type assertion or should I refactor my code in another way?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable case to use a type assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
setFilter(value as Category);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggested solution and then typescript was not happy as follows:

```
Conversion of type 'string' to type 'Tab' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
```

SOLUTION: was to change the value to a number so in this case:

```
setFilter(Number(value));
```